# Different user types table laravel

Tags: laravel, usertype

i have a problem on my project on my user table im using an usertype it has a Student Teacher Admin and i want them to have a separate table with out using an eloquent just a simple query/code or an simple tutorial to help my problem..

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::find();
    return view('teacherpage.teacher_table',  compact('users'));
}
```

teacher_table

```
 @foreach ($users as $position)


                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $position->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $position->first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $position->last_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $position->contact}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $position->department}}</td>


                        <td>{{ $position->usertype}}</td>


                        <td>{{ $position->email}}</td>


                        <th> 
                            <a href="{{action('AdminTableController@edit',['id' =>$position->id])}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit </a>
                    </th>


                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @endforeach
```

**i want to view the Student usertype i don't know please help me **

Comment: What have you tried? Could you add some code?

Comment: i haven't because i dont know where to start

Comment: Your framing of the question contrasts "simple" _against_ Eloquent/Models, so I think you might be looking at this from the wrong angle. You can go ahead and make separate Models for each of the three tables. And you can take a look at the Traits and Interfaces Laravel's out-of-the-box User Model uses to get the framework to recognize them as "user" Models and apply them to your own.. but this part is optional if you don't need those bells and whistles. Personally though, I'd go with MaartenDev's approach of multiple roles as opposed to multiple user tables.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional model makes it possible to assign a type/role to a user. Start by creating the `Role` model:

```
php artisan make:model Role -m
```

and then editing the following migration: `database/migrations/*_*_creates_roles_table.php` to have the following up method:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
}
```

The `Role` model can now be associated with a User by adding a relation to the user model:

> app/User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role(){
        return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
    }
}
```

after migrating the database(`php artisan migrate`) the following code can be used:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('role')->get();
    return view('teacherpage.teacher_table',  compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: i have this error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()**

Comment: I updated it to use `->get()` check the example @JohnCliff